# Is it possible to find public Google calendars?

Tags: google-calendar, search, sharing

I want to embed a Google calendar in my organization's intranet site. Google provides three options for sharing the calendar:

1. Make it visible to anyone in the organization
2. Make it visible only to certain people
3. Make it fully public

In theory option 1 would be good, except that I don't want people to have to be logged in with the right Google account in order to see the embedded calendar. In fact I have 3 Google accounts, and the one for my organization is not the default one in my browser and therefore a calendar that is only visible to people in the organization actually will not display for me and there is no way to make it display.

So it looks like my only choice is to make the calendar public, but then it warns

> "Making your calendar public will make all events visible to the world, including via Google search. Are you sure?"

Now my question is, will it really be visible to the world? How would people find it? I have never found calendar results in a Google search and if I try to find public Google calendars from within the Google Calendar web app all I can find is holidays and phases of the moon.

So I think that the calendar would only be discoverable via the embedded version on our intranet or if anyone shares the link, but since the intranet is private I assume that nobody outside the organization would actually find it. Is that true?

Comment: Is this on the desktop or mobile.  There is a  solution on Android.

Comment: The question is not platform specific. Can you explain what you mean about a solution on Android?

Comment: I use an app called Business Calendar on Android and it can link to multiple accounts to grab the calendars.  So you can have your private one and a shared one.

Comment: I am not sure how this answers my question. My question is how can people discover my public calendar. (I don't want people to discover it.)

Answer (score 0):

If your calendar is public, anyone who knows your email will be able to see your calendar. By default, it will only see when you're busy, i.e. it won't see individual appointment details unless you specify that the specific appointment is public.

Comment: So how can you view someone's calendar, using their email address?

Comment: [https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6294878](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6294878)

Comment: OK, I hadn't noticed that "search for people" field on Google Calendar before. But it seems that only shows the main calendar for the person you search for (if you are allowed to view it). I searched for my work email from my personal email and it simply says "Calendar cannot be shown" even though I have created a public calendar under my work account.